# QoS at the edge of branch

Tags: cisco, qos

I have a question about QoS design in branch. The main place to deploy qos in branch - edge between edge router and ISP. At this edge we have voice traffic to SIP provider, copr. external email and other users traffic (web, torrent). 

We can implement effective qos for outgoing traffic, priority queue for voice and rest for other traffic (general description, I understand that real implementation seems to be more complex). **But what to do with incoming traffic?** For example, I have SIP incoming traffic and torrent to my users, and I think that this p2p traffic will make big latency or even packet loss for my voice traffic.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way for receiver to affect scheduling of sender. You should just work on getting QoS configured at sender.

Theoretically if the frames are correctly classified and your receiver and sender supports 802.1Qbb (essentially CoS aware pause frame) then you could request pausing of BE traffic without causing pausing of EF traffic.

Answer (score 5):

Your provider will need to set up QoS on the PE-CE link. You'll more than likely need to pay for this.

As you noted already, you can only control the CE-PE link which you are already doing.

Answer (score 1):

Some shaping devices such as the Riverbed Steelhead line and the Exinda portfolio offer inbound shaping. These essentially throttle outbound TCP requests as to limit the inbound traffic. In my experience these solutions work decently over low-latency links but give poor results over high latency (satellite) connections.

Comment: The problem with this is that by the time your device has shaped inbound, your WAN link has already been filled with non critical traffic. i.e. it happens too late

Comment: For large requests in particular this is true. For smaller requests, however, it does provide some benefit. You'll never achieve true shaping though unless you're shaping outbound from both ends - which as @mellowd stated, requires an agreement with your provider.